# Groovy AntBuilder: How to get process exit code programmatically from Ant task exec

Tags: groovy, ant

I want to get exit code from a command executed through Ant task `exec`. See below code example.

```
import groovy.ant.AntBuilder

def cmd = 'ls -l'

def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.echo('Hello, Ant Builder!')

ant.exec(executable: 'bash', resultproperty: 'my.cmd.exitCode') {
    arg(value: '-c')
    arg(value: cmd)
}
ant.echo('Exit code is ${my.cmd.exitCode}')

// below return null
def cmdExitCode = ant.properties['my.cmd.exitCode']
println "Exit code: ${cmdExitCode}"

println "Properteis: ${ant.properties}"
```

Below is partial output:

```bash
     [echo] Hello, Ant Builder!
     [exec] total 64
     ...
     [echo] Exit code is 0
Exit code: null
Properteis: [saveStreams:true, current:null, antXmlContext:org.apache.tools.ant.helper.AntXMLContext@78411116, class:class groovy.ant.AntBuilder, antProject:org.apache.tools.ant.Project@aced190, project:org.apache.tools.ant.Project@aced190]
```

The Ant documentation on [exec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) states that

> outputproperty    The name of a property in which the output of the command should be stored. Unless the error stream is redirected to a separate file or stream, this property will include the error output.

It is not clear how to access this property programmatically in Groovy AntBuilder.

Comment: The exit code is always 0, because you hide problems behind the `||
echo`; that might or might not be relevant to the question, but it makes
the real result vanish and you even have to make more gears moving
(`bash -c ...`) to make it going.

Comment: While you are correct about `echo`, it is just one of commands my program is going to execute. They are listed in a configuration file, which are written by other developers, so I have to come up a general solution to execute them, terminate the process if fails and give a helpful hint.

Comment: BTW, I remove `echo` from the example command, so problem is a bit clear since it does not always return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the wrong properties here.  Each `GroovyObject` has
a `getProperties` (or `properties` in Groovy-short-hand).  And the one
from the `AntBuilder` is just what is used to "talk to" `ant`.

The properties you are looking for are in the `Project`, which you can
access on the builder like this:

```
def cmdExitCode = ant.antProject.properties['my.cmd.exitCode']
// XXX                ~~~~~~~~~~
println "Exit code: ${cmdExitCode}"
```